# Class derived from generic type for template some bunch of property

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In my project I try separate domain model from DAO like in example from https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879 . I use for it class which backend state of my domain object which is internal and only use in repository. Next i have my domain object and i want to generic some logic for use it. There is a code:

```
public abstract class GenericEntity<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly T _state;

    internal GenericEntity(T state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    internal T State
    {
        get
        {
            return _state;
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to derived from this class, but my domain model should be public and I cant do that cause of internal DAOEntity.

```
public class DomainModel : GenericEntity<DAOEntity>
{

}

internal class DAOEntity
{

}
```

It is some walk around to it? Or i need to implement this code to manage state in all my class. I dont want to either make some base DAOEntity cause then i need to cast it in all domain models.

EDIT:
Maybe you dont understand my question. Right now i have code which look like Marcos Jonatan Suriani show in his answer:

```
public class Product 
{
  public Product()
  {
    State = new ProductState();
  }

  internal Product(ProductState state)
  {
    State = state;
  }
}

public class ProductState
{

}

public class AgilePMContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<ProductState> Products { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm looking for some design pattern where i could reduce copy paste code with my internal state implementation, so i want to go depper with this solution, cause when i have many domain model this is a code which I need reapet in all.

Comment: I do not see the problem about GenericEntity. Just make DAOEntity class public... As long as you keep State internal you are not leaking responsabilities.

Comment: This is some solution, but in this approach which you suggest, user of library could look into how state is backed and i want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The article purposes a slightly different solution. The main purpose of the pattern is to focus on the Domain Core and avoid workarounds, specially when mapping the domain object to relational (ORM, for ie).

> Taking this approach will help us to stay focused on what really
>   counts the most, our Core Domain and its Ubiquitous Language.

The approach is to have the domain as ubiquitous as it can be by providing state objects - that is going to be used by the ORM (EF). So, the business rules remain on Domain objects and ORM related go to State objects.

> One approach uses a Separated Interface with an implementation class, and the other uses a domain object backed by a state object.

Your implementation should be composed by interfaces that represents the domain (*IProduct*, for instance):

> We create an interface that we want our client to see and we hide the implementation details inside the implementing class.

And also composed by two implementations of the interfaces; one for the Domain object (*Product*), and another for the state object (*ProductState*). The domain implementation should have two constructors:

> a public business constructor for normal clients and a second internal constructor that is used only by internal implementation components.

```
interface IProduct
{
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
  public Product()
  {
    State = new ProductState();
  }

  internal Product(ProductState state)
  {
    State = state;
  }
}

public class ProductState: IProduct
{

}

public class AgilePMContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<ProductState> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do it this right that.But i want to generic the copy paste code with internal method for get state model and constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DomainModel : GenericEntity<DAOEntity>
{

}
```

This is backwards - you've written a domain model that depends on the data model.  You want this dependency to go the other way around: the data model should depend on the domain model.

In a sense, what Vaughn is telling you is that the domain model defines interfaces for data service providers, and the data model implements those providers.

For example, consider a simplified model for banking

```
class DepositModel : BankingApi.Deposit {
    void depositFunds(Account account, Deposit deposit, Clock clock) {

        AccountId currentAccount = account.id();
        AccountId depositInto = deposit.accountId();

        assert depositInto.equals(currentAccount);

        Money amount = deposit.amount();
        account.deposit(amount);

        Time processedAt = clock.now();
        TransactionId transactionId = deposit.transactionId();

        account.updateTransactionHistory(transactionId, processedAt)
    }
}
```

Observe that the model doesn't touch primitive data.  All of the state manipulations are hidden by the value types.

That means your data model can implement structure the data any way you like, and manipulate it in any way that satisfies the specification.

Comment: Why do you inherit from `BankingApi.Deposit`?

Comment: Vernon expose this technique (interfaces for DAL) but choose to abandon this approach. Please read carefully the article again. OP is asking about Domain Object Backed By a State Object section. Could be backwards but considering how hard is to segregate Domain from persistence usign EF I think is a good and simple approach.